# Templates does no exist for rest_framework/API.html

Tags: django

I am going through the tutorial of Django rest framework and API format is not working. The json  format is working though.

The error is templates does not exist rest_framework/API

I am using python3.4 and Django 1.10.6

The rest framework is listed within my installed apps in the settings.py just like described in the docs

The template loader postmortem does not provide the list of tried templates

Comment: Do you have `TEMPLATES['APP_DIRS'] = True` in settings?

Comment: When you get errors that might be due to settings, it's good to open the shell and double check your actual settings. `./manage.py shell` - `from django.conf import settings` - `print settings.INSTALLED_APPS` - `print settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS` - `print settings.__members__` ...

Comment: The templates attributes wasn't set at in my settings. I set it as described in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39307608/4034823